# Candlestick charts component for android

Tags: android, charts, candlestick-chart

I was looking for a candlestick lib chart solution for android, and couldnt find one for a couple of months now.

Im looking for a smooth scrolling, zomming, tooltip, option to polt in a new candle without the need to render the entire chart.

i did come across all the normal options for native code charting:
DriodCharts, AchartEngine, ChartDroid, none of which support candlesticks.
I also used 5 free Javascript and html solutions, all of which are very very slow, and most dont support adding a data tick after the chart has been plotted.

I have seen many free android applications with decent charts and have tried contacting the developers hoping they can at least point me to somewhere, or even sell their lib.

My question is does anyone here know of a native solution for candlesticks in android that supports what i mentioned?

Thanks,
   Totem

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem as you. There is no library in android which directly support candlestick chart. There is no straightforward native solution for your ploblem but if requirement is to particular chart I sugest you to look after [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html)

There's no another way including open source solutions. If you want you can check this out [CandleStick plot by ArtfulBits.](http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/documentation/aicharts/android/index.html)

--EDITED--

Lately [I wrote simple article](http://rpiesnikowski.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-candlestick-chart-with-google.html) how to draw CandleStick Chart in android with small help Google Chart API.

Answer (score 2):

[SciChart for Android](http://www.scichart.com) supports candlestick charts, and brings an extremely fast, real-time charting control to the Android platform.

SciChart is a commercial control but available under royalty free distribution / per developer licensing. There is also free licensing available for [educational use](http://www.scichart.com/educational-discount-programme/) with some conditions.

Some useful links can be found below:

- [Android Candlestick Chart Example](http://www.scichart.com/android-candlestick-chart-example/)
- SciChart's [Android Charts Features](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features)
- [Android Chart Performance Tests](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/) vs. Open Source & Commercial

[image]

*Disclosure: I am the MD of SciChart just so you know!*

Answer (score 1):

Not a free-of-charge product but you might be interested to see the [TeeChart for Android Beta](http://www.steema.com/download/java). 
It includes a Candle Series and support for other financial series and indicators.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can have a look at [NChart3D](http://nchart3d.com/). It is commercial, but comes with a full set of financial chart types.