# Charts for Android

Tags: android, graph, charts

I am working on a project which have some charts (graphs), tick chart, candlestick chart and range chart. But the problem is, there is no library for that charts. I have got Google chart API for candlestick chart. But I don't want graph/chart in a webview.

Example: [Android Candlestick Chart with Google Chart API](http://rpiesnikowski.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-candlestick-chart-with-google.html)

Comment: duplicate of [How to draw charts in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271248/how-to-draw-charts-in-android) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675787/candlestick-charts-component-for-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156740/im-looking-for-fancy-charts-library-for-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730827/android-charts-achartengine-or-androidplot and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424226/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-android and many others

Comment: Got a solution....  link for screenshotz http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html and the sample code: http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/          Anyway, thanks @CommonsWare for ur quick response.

Comment: @ASP is it possible to print those charts in a pdf?

Comment: Simple example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543739/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-android-using-graphview/26562713#26562713

Answer (score 261, accepted):

To make reading of this page more valuable (for future search results) I made a list of libraries known to me.. As @CommonsWare mentioned there are super-similar questions/answers.. Anyway some libraries that can be used for making charts are:

Open Source:

- [AnyChart](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android) (Free for non-commercial, Paid for commercial)
- [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
- [Holo Graph Library](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home)
- [aChartEngine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine)
- [ChartView](https://github.com/brandhill/ChartView)
- [aFreeChart](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/AFreeChart)
- [ChartDroid](https://github.com/kostmo/chartdroid)
- [charts4j](https://github.com/julienchastang/charts4j)
- [GraphView](http://android.arnodenhond.com/components/graphview)
- [AndroidPlot](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src)
- [Drawing the 3D piechart Using Google chart Api](http://androidtutorials60.blogspot.in/2013/06/drawing-3d-piechart-using-google-chart.html)
- [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)
- [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android)
- [ChartProgressBar](https://github.com/hadiidbouk/ChartProgressBar)
- [Plot.ly](http://www.plot.ly)

Paid:

- [aiCharts](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aiCharts.aspx)
- [RChart](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android) (pre Honeycomb - Api 11 UI)
- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/android/shinobicharts/product-tour/) **
- [Steema TeeChart](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steema.teechart.android&hl=en) **
- [Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html) (3D charts for Android)
- [Telerik Rad Chart](http://www.telerik.com/android-ui/chart)
- [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features) (Realtime Charts for Android)

** - means I didn't try those so I can't really recommend it but other users suggested it..

Comment: which one is the best or recommended one from open source

Comment: For 3D PieCharts Google APIs are deprecated, any other option available?

Comment: @Guarav any link to make sure they are deprecated?!

Comment: I just evaluated MPAndroidChart, HoloGraphLibrary, and HelloCharts. I attempted to evaluate a few others, but the links are broken. I selected MPAndroidChart because it has good docs and was able to get it imported into my project, and a working skeleton in a few minutes. HelloCharts and HoloGraphLibrary also look good. Although I had a bit of trouble installing HoloGraphLibrary because of gradle version errors.

Comment: I updated 1 link that I found broken. Let me know if there are more so we can fix them.. thanks for the comment, it is useful for others ;)

Comment: MPAndroidChart seems to be a very complete and customizable option for me. I have only sight checked a few more options, but I can only say good things about MPAndroidChart.

Comment: I want to plot multiple lines in a line chart. These lines intersect with each other and I want to highlight the intersecting points. Which library should I use?

Comment: I suggest Plot.ly for dynamic graphs to plot.

Comment: @Bay feel free to edit original response and add link to it in respective section

Answer (score 4):

SciChart's [Android Graph Library](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features) is a relative newcomer, but brings extremely fast high performance real-time charting to the Android platform.

SciChart is a commercial control but available under royalty free distribution / per developer licensing. There is also [free licensing available](http://www.scichart.com/educational-discount-programme/) for educational use with some conditions.

Some useful links can be found below:

- SciChart's [Android Charts Features](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features)
- [Android Chart Performance Tests](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/) vs. Open Source & Commercial
- [Android Chart Examples](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-examples) and example source code
- [SciChart Quick Start Guide](http://www.scichart.com/getting-started-scichart-android/)
- [Android Charts Documentation](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/current)

[image]

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the SciChart project!*