# Plot and annotate random points

Tags: android, plot, achartengine, graphic

I have tried hard but cannot find a way to plot a number of random points and put a text annotation on each of the point.

My plot is very simple. Here are the points {(1,5),(1,10),(2,3), (7,10),(9,11),(9,13)}
For each of the point plotted, I would like to add a text annotation on top of it.

I have searched high and low looking at scattered chart, bar chart, series chart, etc but cannot find a way to do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was with the same problem, as far as I know achartengine doesn't support annotations currently (I asked on forums).

[Android Plot](http://androidplot.com/) and other free chart solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741300/charts-for-android) doesn't support annotations, the only one is [AFreeChart](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) which is a port of JFreeChart for Android, I am currently using it and it is awesome and has much more features than achartengine.

---

**EDIT:**

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/achartengine/mNAv9owZ7JY), I have modified ace source code to have annotations capabilities.