# How to draw bar chart and also pie chart in android?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I need to draw Bar chart and pie chart in android,i need complete explain and some sample.

I Searched in Google,But i can't understand blow link.If u know any one explain me.

This is Sample Link :
     http://android-graphview.org/

Comment: before post search in google and stack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/772757/1765530

Comment: Have you tried anything from that sample link?

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/q/9741300/1023223

Comment: @InnocentKiller yes i tried.. but i need explain. how its work.. ok

Comment: @appubala yes i searched.i m new for stock overflow and developer

Comment: You can't create pie chart using http://android-graphview.org/  rather i use aChartEngine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link.its work for me.i tried already dude.

http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/07/bar-chart-in-android-using-achartengine.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github library for PieChart
https://github.com/Ken-Yang/AndroidPieChart
and tutorial how to draw Bar chart using AFreeChart
http://www.truiton.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-drawing-achartengine-bar-chart-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you this library, is very easy to use.

[HoloGraphLibrary](http://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary)

you can display BarGraphs, LineGraphs and PieGraphs.

Comment: It is NOT easy to use.The "documentation" does not include how to add library to android project.