# How to create 3D Charts in Android?

Tags: android, 3d

I want to create 3D Charts in my Android app (not a webview). I don't want to use Google Chart Tools as we need internet access on the device.

I tried `achartengine-1.1.0.jar` it doesn't provide 3D view but works fine for 2D view.
 `jfreechart-1.0.17.jar` provides 3D view, I was trying to work on it but I didn't achieve the output. Can anyone please help me with some example on how to implement `jfreechart-1.0.17.jar` on android.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Here, Some libraries are listed. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9741300/1023223

Comment: @Sush19 Have you got the answer??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Orson Charts For Android](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html).

> Orson Charts for Android is a 3D chart library for Android devices that can generate a wide variety of 3D charts for use in mobile apps. Powerful and yet very easy to use, Orson Charts for Android is the perfect tool to provide intuitiive and interactive visualisations to your users.

Also, See this tutorial for [Drawing the 3D piechart Using Google chart Api](http://androidtutorials60.blogspot.in/2013/06/drawing-3d-piechart-using-google-chart.html)

Answer (score 2):

SciChart now supports 3D Charts for both [iOS](https://scichart.com/ios-chart-features) & [Android](https://scichart.com/android-chart-features).

[image]

Chart types include:

- [Android 3D Surface Mesh Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-uniform-mesh/)
- [Android 3D Column Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-uniform-column/)
- [Android 3D Bubble / Scatter Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-bubble/)
- [Android 3D Point Cloud Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-point-cloud/)
- [Android 3D Polar Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-polar-2/)
- [Android 3D Waterfall Chart](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-3d-chart-example-simple-waterfall/)

plus many more ...

All chart types support real-time updates, zooming panning by pinch/drag and tooltips with tap, with support for both Android, iOS and Xamarin.