# How to Create charts like this in android?

Tags: android

some app has very nice charts an UI,  i want to know how they create such a UIand chart like [this](http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/11/expensemanager1.jpg) one.

i know there is some Psd file for that but how to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many libraries in android to create charts some of which are:

1. [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/)
2. [androidplot](http://androidplot.com/)

Also for greater details on the matter you can look at a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716564/2414247) on StackOverflow

Comment: the ones I've mentioned are free. also on the answer I referenced you can find free and paid solutions

Comment: thanks, and that one on the picture, with them can i draw like that? i want a pie chart with percentag in center or a photo in center

Answer (score 0):

[AChartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is probably to most commonly used Android chart library. I have used it on several occasions 
with good results.

I have also heard some good things about [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/), but never tried it myself