# How to draw multi-color segmented circle using OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

What is the best way to draw multi-color segmented circle using OpenCV like below?

What I found, it can be:

1. Using [**cv.fillPoly**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) Many points are required for an arcs accurate drawing, the number of segments is several hundred;
2. Using [**cv.line**](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) by rotating the line in a circle;
3. Using **cv.line** by rotating whole image like in this [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844113/how-to-draw-segmented-circle-like-this-with-certain-requirements).

[image: multicolor segmented circle]

Comment: You can use [`cv.ellipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670) to draw filled arcs starting from the outermost parts. then draw over with the inner parts.

Comment: @Timo Thanks, this is probably the best way, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`cv.ellipse`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69) you can draw segments pretty easily:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

ANGLE_DELTA = 360 // 8

img = np.zeros((700, 700, 3), np.uint8)
img[::] = 255

for size in range(300, 0, -100):
    for angle in range(0, 360, ANGLE_DELTA):
        r = random.randint(0, 256)
        g = random.randint(0, 256)
        b = random.randint(0, 256)
        cv2.ellipse(img, (350, 350), (size, size), 0, angle, angle + ANGLE_DELTA, (r, g, b), cv2.FILLED)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches((8, 8))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

gives

[image: 1]