# Show Details on Pie-Chart android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I need a pie-chart like shown below

[image]

I have searched a lot but most similar case I can find was [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-pie-chart-with-click-event-in-a-custom-xml-layout-using-achartengine/).

[image]

Any ideas...?

Comment: Hi, try this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart and here's a tutorial on how to use it https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335

Comment: i have Already seen that. I need the exact pie-chart shown in image one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741300/charts-for-android

Comment: @TonyVincent thanks. I found a link . I'll check it and tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Can try this...

Pi Chart

You can follow [This](https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts) link....

```
  <view
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
class="im.dacer.androidcharts.PieView"
android:id="@+id/pie_view" />


PieView pieView = (PieView)findViewById(R.id.pie_view);
ArrayList<PieHelper> pieHelperArrayList = new ArrayList<PieHelper>();
pieView.setDate(pieHelperArrayList);
pieView.selectedPie(2); //optional
pieView.setOnPieClickListener(listener) //optional
pieView.showPercentLabel(false); //optional
```

[image]

Also you can follow this Example  [Follow this Answer Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741300/charts-for-android)

Comment: Try this dynamic create...http://www.blazin.in/2013/06/drawing-3d-piechart-using-google-chart.html